# SPL Attacker for spare change ($1)

Tags: plugin, spl, transients

https://www.plugin-alliance.com/en/plugins/detail/spl_attacker.html

Was looking through the free plugins listed on the protooler blog and while it's no longer free, this updated version is only a dollar. Does anyone have it? Tried looking around for reviews but only thing I could find was people reporting about it when it was free. Will probably just get it for the price but I do hate myself for collecting things I don't end up using... Arggghhh

Comment: Whoops and then they must have realized they made a mistake and it's back to $59. Hahahahaha... Sorry

Comment: haha i scored it at $1. couldnt help myself
